# Parameterizing part of sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

the part of the sphere given by:
$$ S = \{ (x,y,z) | x^2+y^2+z^2 = 25, -4 \leq x,y,z \leq 4 \} $$

first Q: I'm not sure if I can apply to this Divergence theorem ? It seem that in order to use it I need to show that certain conditions of the parametrization. In other words, can I show this surface is smooth without finding the parametrization of it ?

second Q: how can I find the parametrization of this surface ? I know the parametrization of a sphere (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametrization+of++sphere ) , so I tried to use it in, for example we can deduce $|cos(v)| < 0.8$, but other condition seem complicated.. so I doubt this is the way to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Q1) Nope. In order to use divergence theorem, the given area should be a boundary of some 3-dimensional object. Instead, you can use Stokes' theorem with $\partial S$ composed with 6 circles of radius 3. (The subset with $|x|,|y|,$ or $|z|=4$) $S$ is a smooth surface with boundary because in any point on the interior of $S$ you can find a local parametrization, for example the one restricting the parametrization of sphere.

Answer to Q2) I think there does not exist single parametrization with barely tolerable expression. What you mentioned is one possibility, or you can use parametrization $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,\pm\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}), |x|,|y|\leq 4$.

Comment: thanks. 
Q1 - if S also included those 6 circles.. could use divergence theorem then? also the local parametrization you are referring is what you give below in Q2 ?

Comment: Answer to 1st) I'm not quite sure that this should be called "divergence" theorem because there is no 3-dimensional object(manifold, to be more precisely). If you are saying the theorem about the equality between integral of curl over some surface and integral of the vector field over its boundary, then you are right, you can use it.

Comment: Answer to 2nd) you can use either of them, the one you wrote on OP or the one I gave.(There is some nasty point, but if you are only interested in calculation, then you may not need to bother)

Comment: wouln't it be the surface of a the body $G = \{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2 < 25, -4<x,y,z<4\}$

Comment: No. $\partial G$ includes other parts, saying $\left\{x^2+y^2\leq 9, z=\pm 4\right\}, \left\{y^2+z^2\leq 9, x=\pm 4\right\}, \left\{z^2+x^2\leq 9, y=\pm 4\right\}$.

Comment: yes. the 6 circles...

Comment: I think I understand. thanks for your time.

Comment: I think there has been some confusion about your terminology... Usually circle means 1-dimensional one and disk is more common word to describe what you called "circle". Anyway, if you understand what I mean, that's cool.

Comment: yes.. English terminology is my bad part...I meant disk.(i.e circle with the area inside).